# Not able to access field through hibernate on oracle database on different userspace with only select privileges

Tags: oracle, hibernate, privileges

I am trying to get use Hibernate for access data from different userspace(where i just have select privileges).I have complete application running with tables in my userspace(so configurations are correct).When i try to get record from different userspace,i am able to see the size of list.However not able to access that collection.

Also when hibernate configuration start, i can see it trying to alter and update, which i would like to stop.Its oracle db .I would like to know where i am doing Wrong because of which i am just getting size but not actual data.

```
Jul 29, 2011 4:39:01 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: table not found: INVENTORY.SWITCHDATA
SEVERE: Unsuccessful: create table INVENTORY.SWITCHDATA (SWITCH_ID number(19,0) not
 null, NAME varchar2(255), NPORTS number(10,0), NUSED number(10,0),     
VENDOR varchar2(255), STYPE varchar2(255), NET varchar2(255), primary key 
(SWITCH_ID))

Jul 29, 2011 4:39:01 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute

SEVERE: ORA-0: insufficient privileges

Jul 29, 2011 5:06:31 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute

INFO: schema update complete

Hibernate: select this_.SWITCHTYPE as y0_, this_.SWITCHTYPE as y1_ from 
INVENTORY.SWITCHDATA this_ group by this_.SType

100
```

do i have to inform about usersspace inventory in some other way then name my table with 'inventory.tablename' or i have to inform about privileges to hibernate somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ORA-0: insufficient privileges` error it's because when hibernate start he try to create and update the database table related to the mapping(hbm files). It's an oracle database error and you should ask DBA to grant the alter create, drop etc.. privileges to the user hibernate is using in the configuration file.

If you dont want hibernate to automatically update the database schema you can check that the properties `Hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is set to `validate` in the hibernate configuration file. The  possible values for this property are: validate | update | create | create-drop. Maybe it is set to `update` in your config file. By disabling the autogeneration of the table schema it will be your responsability to create the table, index, constraint etc..

You can inform hibernate of the schema name to use in the hibernate configuration file with the property `hibernate.default_schema`   and in the `hbm.xml` file in the `<Hibernate-mapping ...`   element

**Reference documentation**

> [Hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) or [Hibernate configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-configuration)
>   The hbm2ddl.auto option turns on automatic generation of database
>   schemas directly into the database. This can also be turned off by
>   removing the configuration option, or redirected to a file with the
>   help of the SchemaExport Ant task.
>
> [hibernate.default_schema](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)
>   Qualify unqualified table names with the given schema/tablespace in
>   generated SQL.  e.g.SCHEMA_NAME
>
> [5.1.2. Hibernate-mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-mapping)
>   This element has several optional attributes. The schema and catalog
>   attributes specify that tables referred to in this mapping belong to
>   the named schema and/or catalog. If they are specified, tablenames
>   will be qualified by the given schema and catalog names. If they are
>   missing, tablenames will be unqualified.

Comment: Thanks for what you informed.It was helpful in getting my partial problem removed.However I am still not able to access exact element in string but able to get size of collection.Have no idea why is happening so.

Comment: What is the code inside getAllSwitchType()? are you closing the hibernate session thats loaded the allSwitch List before iterating it? Are you using a connection pool ? if not see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc and http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool on HowTo configure the C3P0 connection pool