# When i am running this query it is telling comma missing..?

Tags: hibernate

When i am running this query is telling that comma was missing..please check it out.
**This is my query.**

```
INSERT 
    INTO
        VI_STAT_APP
        (STAT_TYPE_ROWID,STAT_REASON_ROWID,STAT_APP_ROWID="3815226") 
    VALUES
        ((SELECT
            stat_reason.STAT_TYPE_ROWID 
        from
            VI_STAT_TYPE stat_type 
        inner join
            VI_STAT_GRP stat_grp 
                on stat_type.STAT_GRP_ROWID=stat_grp.STAT_GRP_ROWID 
        left outer join
            VI_STAT_REASON stat_reason 
                on stat_reason.STAT_TYPE_ROWID=stat_type.STAT_TYPE_ROWID 
        where
            stat_grp.STAT_GRP_NAME="DNB STATUS VALUES - AGMNT"),(SELECT
            stat_reason.STAT_REASON_ROWID 
        from
            VI_STAT_TYPE stat_type 
        inner join
            VI_STAT_GRP stat_grp 
                on stat_type.STAT_GRP_ROWID=stat_grp.STAT_GRP_ROWID 
        left outer join
            VI_STAT_REASON stat_reason 
                on stat_reason.STAT_TYPE_ROWID=stat_type.STAT_TYPE_ROWID 
        where
            stat_grp.STAT_GRP_NAME="DNB STATUS VALUES - AGMNT"));
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Did the error mention which part of the query had the error?

Comment: `STAT_APP_ROWID="3815226"` ... this looks wrong, since you are trying to specify a value in the column name section.

Answer (score 0):

This looks incorrect to me:

```
STAT_APP_ROWID="3815226"
```

The list of column names immediately following `INSERT INTO` is meant precisely for column names, and not for values.  If you want to hard code a value to be inserted for the `START_APP_ROWID` column, then shift it to the `VALUES` section, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO VI_STAT_APP
    (STAT_TYPE_ROWID, STAT_REASON_ROWID, STAT_APP_ROWID) 
VALUES
(
    (SELECT stat_reason.STAT_TYPE_ROWID 
     FROM VI_STAT_TYPE stat_type 
     INNER JOIN VI_STAT_GRP stat_grp 
         ON stat_type.STAT_GRP_ROWID = stat_grp.STAT_GRP_ROWID 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN VI_STAT_REASON stat_reason 
         ON stat_reason.STAT_TYPE_ROWID = stat_type.STAT_TYPE_ROWID 
     WHERE stat_grp.STAT_GRP_NAME = "DNB STATUS VALUES - AGMNT"),
    (SELECT stat_reason.STAT_REASON_ROWID 
     FROM VI_STAT_TYPE stat_type 
     INNER JOIN VI_STAT_GRP stat_grp
         ON stat_type.STAT_GRP_ROWID = stat_grp.STAT_GRP_ROWID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN VI_STAT_REASON stat_reason
         ON stat_reason.STAT_TYPE_ROWID = stat_type.STAT_TYPE_ROWID
     WHERE stat_grp.STAT_GRP_NAME = "DNB STATUS VALUES - AGMNT"),
     "3815226"      // include this value here
);
```

Your current query attempted to mention three columns in the `INSERT INTO` clause while only giving two actual values.

Comment: as you told i did that but now it is giving..org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

 at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
 at

Comment: This seems to be a [completely unrelated error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880215/not-able-to-access-field-through-hibernate-on-oracle-database-on-diferent-userspace-with-only-select-priviliges).

Comment: but one thing It is giving the same error there is nothing wrong in my query?

Comment: Did my answer make your original error go away?  Is the error you mentioned above your current error?

Comment: You have some sort of database permissions problem, as the link above says.  You need to resolve this, and I may not be able to help remotely.